# Sending chimera MD to remote computer

Tags: molecular-dynamics

I am using Terminal to try to run Chimera MD simulations on a remote server/computer. I have been able to successfully connect using the command ssh username@detroit05 (and then entering the password). However, I want to be able to send a command to a remote computer to improve the computational time especially when running multiple MD simulations; right now, I am running MD simulations on the same computer. I was first thinking of a sequence of commands below:

```
Ctrl+Z
bg
ssh -y username@detroit05
```

I know that the Ctrl+Z command temporarily pauses a command, but I believe that the jobs command is first needed to list the current running jobs (that Ctrl+Z can be performed on). However, the running jobs are not listed when I type “jobs”. After using the “top” command to list all of the processes, I have verified that the Kill command works by typing these in succession:

```
Kill -STOP PID#
Kill -CONT PID#
```

Can you walk me through how to first have a listing of jobs running in Chimera and then sending it to a remote computer?